# Test Accuracy same as Training Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, model, k-nearest-neighbour, learning

I am building a prediction model using KNN. After experimenting the data using KFOLD Cross Validation technique, I've got the mean accuracy and applied them on the real model and it turns out that the Test Accuracy is equivalent to the Training Accuracy. Is it normal to have this kind of case?

Comment: Why do you think that test accuracy cannot be equal to training accuracy?

Comment: Without a further explanation of what your process is it is hard to say, but my guess is that this has something to do with the fact that you are using KNN. Training accuracy for KNN is kind of a misnomer as there is no model being trained

Comment: @astel why a misnomer? For k=1 yes, but for every other k, the training accuracy gives you a reasonable estimate of accuracy on “seen data”.

Answer (score 0):

Say that your data is photos of cars from New York City, including regular cars and yellow cabs. You are building a cab classifier. You split your data randomly to train and test set and assess accuracy. Say that your algorithm has learned to classify all yellow cars as cabs. If the split was random, you would expect similar proportion of yellow cars in train and test set, hence similar accuracy.

Having same value of the metric in train and test set can mean that your results are good, or bad, depending on context. In the cab classifier, they would be equally bad. On another hand, if the classifier leaned to classify cab-shaped yellow cars as cabs, than it could be quite ok if you want to use it for cars in New York City, but would be useless for cars in other parts of the world, where you can find non-yellow cabs as well. So TL;DR is that you need to inspect the results to understand better what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that it is *exactly* the same, I'd be concerned there's a bug in your pipeline or how you're collecting the results. But if you mean roughly the same, no, there's nothing odd about the test accuracy being close to the mean k-fold validation accuracy. You'd normally expect the test accuracy to potentially be a *little* bit better, since you're using a larger (and in the kNN case, denser) training set.